# what is the best way to store my 2D data

Tags: python, list

I am using Python2.7.

I have a 2D array like this:

```
[[ 0, 12,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [57, 69, 68, 67, 75, -1, -1, -1],
 [19, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [ 1, 18, 19, 11,  5, -1, -1, -1],
 [16,  9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [54, 66, 65, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```

`-1` is just a flag for empty nodes.

I need to search through the elements of the array, manipulate the elements and update the array for thousand times. So far the array is small, when the size increases to 8*500. The manipulation will be too time-and-memory consuming.

Is there any advantage to store the array in this way?

```
[[26, 12, 6],
 [57, 69, 68, 67, 75],
 [19, 21],
 [28, 18, 19, 11, 5],
 [16, 9, 10],
 [54, 66, 65]]
```

In this way, during the data manipulation, I need to do appending or deleting.

What is the best way to store my data? Many thanks

Comment: That's a list not array.

Comment: Have a look at sparse [matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

Comment: I personally would use a numpy masked array or pandas dataframe

Comment: You might well be able to get more focused answers if you're able to describe the kinds of operations you wish to perform.

Comment: Additionally, a 8*500 array is not that big in terms of data storage/manipulation, and operating on it with vectorized numpy functions will be practically instant.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary some folks might disagree :) http://metarabbit.wordpress.com/2013/12/05/im-doubling-down-on-a-mistake/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try using a sparse matrix from SciPy. [SciPy: Sparse Matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) The specific one you want to use would depend on the calculations that you are doing.

```
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy import *

row  = array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,7,7,7])
col  = array([0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,2])
data = array([0,12,6,57,69,68,67,75,19,21,1,18,19,11,5,16,9,10,54,66,65])

M = csr_matrix( (data, (row,col)), shape = (8,8))

>>> M.todense()
Out[34]:
matrix([[ 0, 12,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [57, 69, 68, 67, 75,  0,  0,  0],
        [19, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1, 18, 19, 11,  5,  0,  0,  0],
        [16,  9, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [54, 66, 65,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

This would take up must less space in memory (for large matrices) and slicing/iterating over rows is fast. (But it is slow slicing, iterating over columns.)

Comment: Many thanks. After using M.todense(), is it possible to change empty entries to -1, so that it will not conflict with the effective data 0?

Comment: I would write a pair of loops. The outer loop going over the rows. The inner loop going over the columns **starting from the end** and working backward. While the value at the current position is equal to zero, set it to -1. When it isn't zero, break out of the inner loop, and move on to the next row.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good case for a numpy masked array or a pandas DataFrame. Here's why:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

# plain numpy arrays don't know what -1 actually means
myArr = np.array([
 [0, 12, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [57, 69, 68, 67, 75, -1, -1, -1],
 [19, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 18, 19, 11, 5, -1, -1, -1],
 [16, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [54, 66, 65, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
])
print(myArr.mean(axis=1))
[  1.625  41.625   4.25    6.375   3.75   -1.     -1.     22.5  ]

# masked arrays do (if you tell them)
myMArr = np.ma.masked_equal(myArr, -1)
print(myMArr.mean(axis=1))
[6.0 67.2 20.0 10.8 11.666666666666666 -- -- 61.666666666666664]

# and so do dataframes
myDF = pandas.DataFrame(myMArr)
print(myDF.mean(axis=1))

0     6.000000
1    67.200000
2    20.000000
3    10.800000
4    11.666667
5          NaN
6          NaN
7    61.666667
dtype: float64
```

I greatly prefer dataframes over masked arrays. The most obvious reason is the default REPRs

masked array:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[0 12 6 -- -- -- -- --]
 [57 69 68 67 75 -- -- --]
 [19 21 -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [1 18 19 11 5 -- -- --]
 [16 9 10 -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [54 66 65 -- -- -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = -1)
```

dataframe(text version):

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   0  12   6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  57  69  68  67  75 NaN NaN NaN
2  19  21 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   1  18  19  11   5 NaN NaN NaN
4  16   9  10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7  54  66  65 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

In an IPython Notebook you get a nice HTML REPR of dataframes:
[image]

Comment: That's pretty nice, +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am afraid the mask might take up extra space in memory.Is that right?

Comment: @Shirley Yes. However, I don't think that an 800x5 boolean array is cause for much concern. That said, I still highly recommend going with pandas dataframes.